# Utility to insert text when a hot key is pressed

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, hotkeys, paste

I am looking for an utility that inserts (pastes) text into the active application, when a hot-key is pressed.

The utility I am looking for should allow to use of tokens in the text (in example `@date`, which should be replaced with the current date), to define custom tokens, and to allow to create different combinations hot-key => text to insert.

Comment: Under Windows, AutoHotKey can do this very simply - you may have better luck searching for alternatives to specific software, rather than features. I know I've used mac software to refine searches for windows and linux software, before.

Comment: this might be a duplicate of [AutoHotKey equivalent on Mac](http://superuser.com/questions/28023/autohotkey-equivalent-on-mac) @phoshi ... ?

Comment: @quack quixote: It's probable that the answers given to the question you report would probably be given to this question too. Consider that Mac users would probably not know what that Windows utility does, and that somebody looking for a Mac utility with a specific purpose will not look at all the questions were the author is asking for the equivalent of XYZ for Mac.

Comment: @Phoshi: If I would know an application that has the feature I am looking for, then I would not probably ask the question here; I would probably ask which application is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [TypeIt4Me](http://www.ettoresoftware.com/products/typeit4me/) or [TextExpander](http://www.smileonmymac.com/TextExpander/).

Answer (score 1):

I like [Typinator](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/18028/typinator)

[image]

> Typinator is for you if you've ever experienced the tedium and frustration of having to repeatedly type your name, e-mail address, home page url, and other words or phrases again, again and again. Or if you frequently need to quickly insert images like your signature, location plan, or company logo into documents.
>
> Typinator boosts your productivity and eliminates errors by automating the process of inserting frequently used text and graphics and and auto-correcting typos and misspelled words.

Comment: Typinator doesn't allow to define custom tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [QuickSilver](http://docs.blacktree.com/quicksilver/quicksilver) loaded, you can also create a [keyboard trigger](http://docs.blacktree.com/quicksilver/triggers).  The "Select an item" field is the raw text (enter the raw text by starting with a period) and the "Action" field is "Type text".  Create the command in the Trigger panel of the QuickSilver preference screen, then double click the line under the "Trigger" column to set the hotkey.

Note, if you are using Snow Leopard, you'll need the [forked version](http://github.com/tiennou/blacktree-alchemy/downloads) in order to get it to work.

Comment: I tried QuickSilver, but I didn't find a way to use tokens in the text to replace. The reason I decided to not use it is that I found an interview with Quicksilver author where he suggests to use different utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I found [QuicKeys 4](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) too. It allows to paste text taken from a list of clips defined from the user, when a combination of keys is used; to visualize a list of clips from which to choose the text to copy; to expand the text entered, with the possibility to use Applescript to create tokens.