# Mac Autohotkey Substitute

Tags: mac, autohotkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AutoHotKey equivalent on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/28023/autohotkey-equivalent-on-mac)

I want to see if there is a substitute for AHK on the Mac that allows me to do a script like rapid left clicks?

Comment: also see http://superuser.com/questions/28023/autohotkey-equivalent-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

Hah, I was looking into this literally minutes ago, and found this:

> http://www.ironahk.net/

Its a .NET port of AutoHotKey that supposedly works on Macs, but I didn't try it, the [documentation](http://www.ironahk.net/docs/) was poor.

I was only looking for keyboard shortcuts and text expansion.